# Background Noise Reduction in Audio signal

Tags: highpass-filter, noise-cancellation

I using high pass filter  for reduction or removal of noise of audio signal but still some noise is there in signal.i have MIC,Head Set,Bluetooth and phone are connected to controller,while talking on MIC some background is there.How to reduce the noise and is there any algorithm for it.let me know please.

Im implementing in c code structure.

Any Algorithms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a bit on the type of noise. If it's hum or buzz, you need to clean up your recording electronics and if push comes to shove you may be able to notch it out.

Real acoustic background noise is difficult to remove. You may want to read up on "blind source separation". Here are a few examples http://cnl.salk.edu/~tewon/Blind/blind_audio.html

Comment: thanks for reply,

but my question is we usually talking on phone calls over Bluetooth,so,there will be some algorithm or techniques to reduce the noise.Same thing i implemented im my project.while i talking on mic,the voice is not so much clear.

is there algorithm to reduce that?

Comment: @mani Welcome to SE.DSP!  Please [take the tour](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour) and understand better how this forum works. You are using it in such a way that will annoy many people.

Comment: can anybody suggest me?